# Deploying war to remote tomcat server without breaking the integration tests execution

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-plugin, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am using `tomcat7-maven-plugin` for running my integration tests on my localhost Tomcat using `mvn verify` command. However, when I run `mvn tomcat7:redeploy` I want to deploy the war to my remote tomcat server instead of localhost tomcat. How can I achieve this? Please guide.

**pom.xml**

```
  <!-- Embedded integration testing with localhost Tomcat -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>start-tomcat</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run-war</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shutdown</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <!-- Integration tests -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I face the same problem at the moment. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope, I ditched the idea of using embedded Tomcat server altogether.